# how is __v_isReactive flag set to true in vue reactivity

Tags: vue.js

Hi everyone I am trying to understand reactivity in vue 3 using proxy, by looking through the vue core library for package reactivity.

In reactive.ts file function name createReactiveObject
In the code below I am not able to find when is IS_REACTIVE flag added on target when creating proxy.
Please let me know if anyone could help me understanding the code

```
if (
    target[ReactiveFlags.RAW] &&
    !(isReadonly && target[ReactiveFlags.IS_REACTIVE])
  ) {
    console.log('keys ', target.hasOwnProperty(ReactiveFlags.IS_REACTIVE)) // 'keys ' false
    console.log(
      'target[ReactiveFlags.IS_REACTIVE] ',
      target[ReactiveFlags.IS_REACTIVE]
    ) // 'target[ReactiveFlags.IS_REACTIVE] ' true

    return target
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target` is a proxy, the flag is set in [proxy handler](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/v3.3.11/packages/reactivity/src/baseHandlers.ts#L97-L98) when `target[ReactiveFlags.IS_REACTIVE]` is accessed:

```
  get(target: Target, key: string | symbol, receiver: object) {
    const isReadonly = this._isReadonly,
      shallow = this._shallow
    if (key === ReactiveFlags.IS_REACTIVE) {
      return !isReadonly
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of `reactive()`. ReactiveFlags.IS_REACTIVE is implemented in `get` where IS_REACTIVE = `__v_isReactive`.

```
function reactive(obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, key, receiver) {
      track(target, key);
      if (key === "__v_raw") {
        return target;
      }
      if (key === "__v_isReactive") {
        return true;
      }
      return Reflect.get(target, key, receiver);
    },
    set(target, key, value, receiver) {
      const result = Reflect.set(target, key, value, receiver);
      trigger(target, key);
      return result;
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: ["First answers" feedback:] This answer looks helpful and professional, including the code sample. (I can't evaluate it from content perspective, as I'm not too much into that topic.)